# How to add accents to letters in java

Tags: java, unicode, diacritics, unicode-string, codepoint

I am trying to combine alphabetical characters with accents in java. For example:
Combining the letter "e" (\u0065) with a combing grave accent (\u0300).
I have attempted numerous ways in java and believe I should use java.text.Normalizer but cannot figure out how to do it.

I have attempted the following:

```
String combinedLetter = Normalizer.normalize("\u0065\u0300", Form.NFKD);
```

And

```
Char CombinedLetter = (char) (0+0065 + 0+0300));
```

But neither have worked thus far, any ideas on how to do this? I cannot just use the character for é as I need to do this for every alphabetic character.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("e", "\u0065\u0300");` will do that for you. But why not replace with Unicode e grave?

Comment: `Normalizer`, though related, is not the tool for the job *you described*

Comment: You can't have a single `char` for that it is a string of e + combining grave accent  - two characters. For some combinations you can use the single character equivalent - \u00e8 "e with grave accent" but there may not be a single character equivalent for all characters. `Normalizer.normalize("\u0065\u0300", Form.NFC)` will convert to the single character if possible.

Comment: Some  basic Java points: A `char` in Java is an integer primitive. So, `(0+0065 + 0+0300)` won't work because combining characters isn't done via arithmetic addition.   It adds 4 integers: `0`, `53`, `0`, `192`, giving `245`. It's `53`, `192`, and `245` in decimal  because an integer literal with a `0` first digit is Octal. Perhaps you meant  `(0x0065 + 0x0300)` to use two hexadecimal literals?  And did you mean `Char` or `char` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard. No need to call any normalizer. No need for casting.

### Avoid `char`

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physical incapable of representing most characters.

### Code point

To work with individual characters, use Unicode [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers. You will find code point methods on various classes such as `String`, `StringBuilder`, and `Character`.

Here is an example using code point numbers in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) within a `String` literal.

```
System.out.println( "\u0065\u0300" ) ;
```

> è

Here is an example using appending code point numbers in decimal via [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). 65 hex is 101 decimal, and 300 hex is 768 decimal.

```
String output = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint( 101 ).appendCodePoint( 768 ).toString() ;
System.out.println( output ) ;
```

> è

See that code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/1uOgwv).

Any Unicode-savvy text renderer software knows to combine the letter plus [diacritic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)(s) for display. Learn about [combining characters is digital typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) at Wikipedia.

| Character | Name | Decimal | Hex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e | LATIN SMALL LETTER E | 101 | 65 |
| ` | COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT | 768 | 300 |

For more info, see:

- [*Combining Diacritical Marks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) at Wikipedia.
- [*Combining Diacritical Marks | Range: 0300–036F*](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf) at the Unicode Consortium. (PDF)
- [*Basic Latin (Unicode block)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) at Wikipedia.
- [*C0 Controls and Basic Latin | Range: 0000–007F*](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) at the Unicode Consortium.